# Does Codeigniter have a default Session value?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Even if I use session_destroy() in my logout controller `var_dump($_SESSION);` gives some output like array(1) `{ ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1484032559) }` after user has logged out.
For this reason I think the following code for login controller is not working properly:

```
function login()
{
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
  {
    $this->load->view("log");
  }

  else
  {
    /********login details verification*******/
  }
```

If so is the case how to destroy session after user logout?
Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Comment: use the codeigniter destroy and get session function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CodeIgnitor native session destroy method, it should work fine as CodeIgnitor use it's own session mechanism.

```
e.g,
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

to unset any session value use following syntax

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('variable');
```

Reference
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session%20destroy#destroying-a-session